# Percorrer vários diretórios em terminal Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

Eu tenho um algoritmo que se inicia com um arquivo. Desse arquivo, ele gera vários outros. Eu preciso pegar todos os nomes desses arquivos gerados, para a partir deles, executar novamente meu algoritmo.
Basicamente eu queria saber como fazer em Shell Script para percorrer todos os arquivos de um diretório e de seus subdiretórios.
Pensei em algo recursivo, mas como não tenho conhecimento em Shell, fiquei meio perdido.

Comment: Utilize o [find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

Answer (score -1):

Use o *grep* e um *for loop*.

Exemplo:

```
$ grep -R stretch /etc/*
```